# How to dismiss a UIPresentationController by tapping its dimming view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uipresentationcontroller

I am using a `UIPresentationController` to show a custom modal. the presentation controller has a `UIView` dimming view animated in an out when it is being shown. The modal itself is a `UIViewController` added to the presentation controller's container.

#### The problem

I can only call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]` from the embedded UIViewController. But I cannot do the same from the `UIPresentationController`. But that's where the dimming view is.

I'd like to avoid adding additional invisible views to the modal or use `NSNotificationCenter` if possible.

How do you dismiss a `UIPresentationController` by tapping its dimming view? Does it make sense? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I found it. You can reach the shown UIViewController to dismiss via `self.presentedViewController`

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: where did you put this? it's not working for me. I'm getting the error 
unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Got it to work. Apparently I wasn't setting the target for gesture recognizer properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (!self.tapOutsideRecognizer) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOutsideRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapBehind:)];
        self.tapOutsideRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        self.tapOutsideRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        self.tapOutsideRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:self.tapOutsideRecognizer];
    }
}

- (void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:nil];

        if (![self.view pointInside:[self.view convertPoint:location fromView:self.view.window] withEvent:nil]) {
            [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer:sender];

            [self back:sender];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: That's the problem. There is no `dismissViewControllerAnimated` in the `UIPresentationController`

Answer (score 0):

Yahh it is possible..
first you have to add Tap gesture on dimming view and add in Tap gesture action...

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

this will solve your problem.